# Runnable posted in another runnable not executed

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I'm trying to run a runnable from another runnable using Handler.post() method of my singleton but this second runnable is not being run until after the original runnable finishes. In the example code below I am calling MyManager,getInstance().startCommand() from somewhere in the application. The myRun variable in the MyCommand class has a sleep put on the thread so I can test a timeout feature, but the runnable called mTimeoutTimer is not be executed until AFTER the myRun runnable is finished. Why is this happening, and how can I change that?

```
public class MyManager{
    private MyManager sInstance;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mTimeoutTimer;

    public static MyManager getInstance(){
        if(sInstance == null){
            sInstance = new MyManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private MyManager(){
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mTimeoutTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(“RUNNABLE RUNNING!”);
        }
    };

    public class MyCommand {
       private Runnable myRun;

       public MyCommand(){
           myRun = new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   MyManager.getInstance().startTimeoutTimer();

                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(COMMAND_TIMEOUT_MILLIS * 3);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                   MyCommand.this.execute();
               }
           };
       }

       public void execute() {
           myRun.run();
       }
    }


    private void startTimeoutTimer(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeoutTimer);
    }


    public void startCommand(){
        new MyCommand().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because Handler are called in the Main thread so it will wait for the other one to finished

instead put your other handler in the `HandlerThread` to run your handler on a separate thread

```
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    thread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
```

The documentation of [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)

```
  Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper.
  The looper can then be used to create    handler classes. 
  Note that start() must still be called.
```

Comment: I am having issues implementing this, here's the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173049/using-handlerthread-and-handler-on-a-separate-thread-freezes-ui-thread

Answer (score 1):

A single thread cannot execute two `Runnables` at once (or *any* two things at once, really).

If you post both to the `Handler` instances bound to the same thread (generally the UI thread) then one will necessarily have to wait for the other to finish.

To run in another thread, use

```
new Thread(mTimeoutTimer).start();
```

Or you can use a thread pool. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html).

Comment: so how can I run mTimeoutTimer in another thread? should I just create a thread manually using the Thread class?

Comment: i would use newThread().start() but i need to be able to stop the thread and start in with a delaty, so I'm going to stick with using a Handler for that.