# Using HandlerThread and Handler on a separate thread freezes UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, ui-thread

In my project, I want to implement a timer in another thread that counts down the time spent executing a certain method in my application, and do something if it is taking too much time. When executing the MyManager.startCommand() method, the application is freezing and I don't know why since I think I am not doing anything on the UI thread. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I had originally asked this question and was not experiencing an app freeze, so I don't think it's because I'm sleeping the thread: [Runnable posted in another runnable not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172356/runnable-posted-in-another-runnable-not-executed).

```
public class MyManager{
    private MyManager sInstance;
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mTimeoutTimer;

    public static MyManager getInstance(){
        if(sInstance == null){
            sInstance = new MyManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private MyManager(){
        mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("mHandlerThread");
        mHandlerThread.start();
        mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
        mTimeoutTimer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e(“RUNNABLE RUNNING!”);
            }
    };

    public class MyCommand {
       private Runnable myRun;

       public MyCommand(){
           myRun = new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   MyManager.getInstance().startTimeoutTimer();
                   MyCommand.this.run();
               }
           };
       }

       public void execute() {
           myRun.run();
       }

       abstract public void run();
    }


    private void startTimeoutTimer(){
        mHandler.post();
    }


    public void startCommand(){
        new MyCommand().execute();
    }
}
```

And how I'm using a MyCommand object:

```
MyCommand command =
new MyCommand() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //make api call that happens in another thread
    }
};
```

So I am basically trying to create the timeout timer for that API call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Just wrap your first runnable in a Thread.

```
public class MyManager{
private MyManager sInstance;
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mTimeoutTimer;

public static MyManager getInstance(){
    if(sInstance == null){
        sInstance = new MyManager();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private MyManager(){
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread();
    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
    mTimeoutTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e(“RUNNABLE RUNNING!”);
        }
};

public class MyCommand {
    private Thread th;
    private Runnable myRun;

   public MyCommand(){
       myRun = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               MyManager.getInstance().startTimeoutTimer();

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(COMMAND_TIMEOUT_MILLIS * 3);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

               MyCommand.this.execute();
           }
       };
       th = new Thread(myRun);
   }

   public void execute() {
       th.start();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeoutTimer);
   }
}


private void startTimeoutTimer(){
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeoutTimer);

}


public void startCommand(){
    new MyCommand().execute();
}
```

}

Also you forgot to start the `mHandlerThread`

```
    private void startTimeoutTimer(){
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeoutTimer);

}
```

Comment: I actually did start the Handlerthread, I just forgot to add that line. And the MyCommand class is me trying to simplify what's really happening in the code, I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: See my updated question please. I can't use a separate thread to run the MyCommand because it's making an API call that already happens in a separate thread.

Comment: @mpellegr can you further explain what api call you are doing?

Comment: it's a third party library not an android API call. All I can say is that the API call will run on another thread anyway, so I don't think me putting the MyCommand.myRun field on another thread is a good idea.

Comment: @mpellegr and on which thread is it running cause you can call that thread and run your api

Comment: I don't have access to the thread this library creates, all I know is it isn't the UI thread. I understand now that the Thread.sleep is causing the app to hang because it's executing on the UI thread, but I don't know any other way I cant test that my timeout timer will work if the API ever hangs.

Comment: @mpellegr impossible that it has its own Thread. if it has its own thread then it is unusable to the fact that you call that API somewhere in your code which run a different thread.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I didn't catch this. MyCommand originally implemented Runnable. I'm basically trying to wrap that run() command with a timer that will time how long it takes to run, I guess my setup is flawed and I should instead just start and stop my timer in every single MstCommand object in the run method. Not what I wanted to do but I think that's all that's possible.

Comment: @mpellegr If you really want to record how long the method takes use the native System.currentTimeMillis(); on a single thread

Comment: I need to show a toast message if a certain amount of time has passed by, hence why I use the timeout timer on another thread.